# pset 3 - recover - code only outputs one image and debug 50 quits

Tags: c, cs50, recover

I followed the pseudocode of pset 3 recover and my code only outputs one image and the debugger(debug50) quits after looping 4th time in the `number = fread(buffer, 1, 512, file);` line.

I checked the hexadecimal values of my output jpeg and turns out it's also incorrect when compared to the raw file. i can discern the image but some of the hexadecimals are deviated by small numbers.I

```c
// open card file 
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s", argv[1]);
    return 2;
}

// buffer
unsigned char *buffer = malloc(513);
buffer[512] = 0x00;

// number
int number = 512;

// bool
int jpegFound = 0;

// jpeg number
int jpegNum = 0;

// jpeg name  
char *jpegName = malloc(8);
jpegName[7] = 0x00; 

// jpeg file pointer
FILE *jpegPtr;

// iterate through all the blocks of the card
while (1)
{
    // read 512 bytes into a buffer
    number = fread(buffer, 1, 512, file);

    // break out of the loop if its the EOF
    if (number != 512)
    {
        break;
    }

    // check whether its the start of a new jpeg
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        // have we already found a jpeg?
        if (jpegFound == 1)
        {
            // close previous jpeg file
            fclose(jpegPtr);

            // store the jpegName in a string
            sprintf(jpegName, "%03i.jpg", jpegNum);

            // open a new file with the stored jpeg name
            jpegPtr = fopen(jpegName, "w");

        }
        else
        {
            // we found a jpeg finally
            jpegFound = 1;

            // store the jpeg Name in a string
            sprintf(jpegName, "%03i.jpg", jpegNum);

            // open a new file with the stored jpeg name
            jpegPtr = fopen(jpegName, "w");
        }

        // write buffer to the jpeg
        fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, jpegPtr);
    }
    else
    {
        if (jpegFound == 1)
        {
            // these bytes are part of the previous jpeg
            fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, jpegPtr);
        }
        else
        {
            // this means that these bytes can be discarded
        }
    }
}

// close any remaining files
fclose(jpegPtr);

// free the memory we used in malloc
free(buffer);
free(jpegName);

// return 0
return 0;
```

expected output of `./recover card.raw` to be many images but only got one image which looks okay but some of its hexadecimal values are deviated slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I wasn't incrementing `jpegNum` , also, as far as `debug50` is concerned i still dont know what is causing it to quit.